# How can I count cells using for loop in r? (table() is not applicable)

Tags: r

This is the sample data.

```
created_date  start_date
2014-12-11    2014-12-10
2014-12-11    2014-12-11
2014-12-12    2014-12-13
2014-12-13    NULL       
2014-12-13    2014-12-13
2014-12-13    2014-12-13
2014-12-23    NULL
2014-12-23    NULL
```

I'd like to count how many start_date was checked each day, according to the created_date. The value of start_date is not important, only the 'number' of start_dates checked is meaningful.

In this case, the result of for loop should be like this

```
created_date  count
2014-12-11     2 
2014-12-12     1
2014-12-13     2
2014-12-23     0
```

I cannot simply use table() because:

table(created_date) will count created_date, not start_date.

```
>table(created_date)

created_date  count
2014-12-11     2 
2014-12-12     1
2014-12-13     3
2014-12-23     2
```

table(start_date) won't work either, since it doesn't count the created date of "NULL" and more importantly, the value of start_date itself is meaningless.

```
>table(start_date)

created_date  count
2014-12-10     1 
2014-12-11     1
2014-12-13     3
NULL           3
```

I guess for loop should be used, but don't have idea how to code that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added why this question is different from the existing one.
table() doesn't work for this code

Comment: The way the question is currently written, you *can* use `table` and it will do exactly what you want — you just need to remove rows with `NULL` beforehand!

Comment: @KonradRudolph
Thanks for your comment!
But if I remove rows with NULL and use table, 

created_date  Count
2014-12-23     0

this will not appear. 
What I want to do is counting the number of start_date with value for each created_date.

Comment: Fair point. How about creating two tables: one for all data, and one for the `NULL` data only (= removing all nonnull rows), and then subtract the second from the first?

Comment: What do you mean by subtracting the second from the first? 
How is it different from removing rows with NULL as you recommended at first?

Comment: It’s not the same thing. Unfortunately it’s too complicated to explain in a comment, and since this question is still closed I couldn’t write an answer. So I’ve uploaded an explanation with the code on Github instead: https://gist.github.com/klmr/b7fd96c113e24c178d2630b66bb73a15

Comment: @akrun Mind reopening the question? It’s really not a duplicate …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version:** Use `table` separately on the complete data and on the empty rows only, subtract second from first.

**Long version:**

Assuming your data is in `x` (and that `NULL`s are actually `NA`s, [see Gist for details](https://gist.github.com/klmr/b7fd96c113e24c178d2630b66bb73a15)):

Count the entries, and put them into `data_frame`s for convenience:

```
library(dplyr)
all_counts = as_data_frame(table(x$created_date))
na_counts = as_data_frame(table(x[is.na(x$start_date), ]$created_date))
```

Subtract the `na_counts` from the `full_counts`. To do this, we
first need to join these two tables. Joining will introduce `NA`s, which we
will replace by `0`s:

```
full_join(all_counts, na_counts, by = 'Var1') %>%
    mutate(n.y = ifelse(is.na(n.y), 0, n.y)) %>%
    mutate(count = n.x - n.y) %>% # And finally, subtract the counts.
    select(created_date = Var1, count)
```

Result:

```
| created_date   |   count |
|:---------------|--------:|
| 2014-12-11     |       2 |
| 2014-12-12     |       1 |
| 2014-12-13     |       2 |
| 2014-12-23     |       0 |
```